# How do I change GPS elements on the Betaflight OSD for my Acrobee Lite?

Tags: betaflight, osd, gps

Right now I'm on Betaflight trying to change the OSD for my AcroBee Lite and it's being really weird, I can't seem to get more than three little thingies to be shown at once. Is there some sort of secret code I need or something? This is really confusing. I'm trying to have the altitude, artificial horizon, battery usage, compass bar, crosshair, GPS speed, home direction, home distance, RSSI value, and warnings shown.

I got everything laid out on Betaflight, but when I clicked save and then checked it on my drone it wasn't right. Currently, I have the horizon, crosshair, compass bar, and altitude showing but I don't know how to get the rest on. Sometimes when I change a box something will appear and another disappears.

How do I change my OSD?

---

**EDIT:** apparently some of the elements were just getting cut off the edge of the screen so I moved everything to the center and a few more appeared but I still can't get home distance/direction and speed.

**EDIT2:** I have the following elements on the OSD; compass bar, battery usage, crosshair, altitude, RSSI value, and I think warnings. I want to add the GPS speed, home direction and distance but am unsure how. Every element I have enabled right now has boxes 2 and 3 checked, but I can't get the GPS speed and home direction/distance to show up. What do I need to change?

**EDIT3:** AcroBee Lite apparently does not have GPS so problem solved i guess.

Comment: Is it possible that your drone does not have a GPS? That would explain why speed and home distance don't work, as those both require the use of a GPS.

Comment: @JacobB, thats a good point, it would seem that the acrobee lite does not have gps, my bad.

Comment: For our site stats, would one of you mind posting this as an answer and getting it accepted? :) I like how high our answered question rate is and I think it'd be good to keep it high.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the AcroBee Lite does not have gps functions so adding gps functions to the osd is impossible.